# backbone.js collections fetch - neither success nor error function triggers

Tags: backbone.js

In the below code, I see that the collection initializer fires. I can also make the model initializer fire a different number of times based on server-side query mods that adjust the number of database hits, so I feel confident my fetch is hitting the server. However, I never get an alert after fetch. Can somebody please correct what is surely a mistake on my part?

```
$(function () {

    Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            alert("Model Init");
        }
    });

    PersonList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Person,
        url: '/Tfount_Email/Email/SOAInbox',
        initialize: function () {
            alert("Collections Init");
        }
    });

    var personlist = new PersonList;

    /*
    personlist.fetch().complete(function () {
    alert("done");
    });
    */

    personlist.fetch(
        {
            error: function () {
                alert("error!!"); 
            }
        },
        {
            success: function () {
                alert("no error"); 
            }
        }
    );



});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

```
$(function () {
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                alert("Model Init");
            }
        }),
        PersonList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Person,
            url: '/Tfount_Email/Email/SOAInbox',
            initialize: function () {
                alert("Collections Init");
            }
        }),
        personlist = new PersonList();

    personlist.fetch({
       error: function () {
         alert("error!!"); 
       },
       success: function () {
          alert("no error"); 
       }
    }).complete(function () {
        alert("done");
    });
});
```

Notes:

- I added the `var` keyword for `Person` and `PersonList`, you forgot that.
- `fetch()` returns a jQuery XHR object. You should bind the `complete` callback right with the call.
- `fetch()` accepts one options hash, not multiple ones.

Comment: Thank you! Note you got to my post before I could edit the mis-spelled succcess (3 c's) to correct spelling in my OP. Even with correct spelling of 'success' in my OP my code exhibited the problem as I reported. Tomalak's solution fixed.

Comment: @goldfinger You're welcome. BTW, you can edit not only your own, but other people's posts, too. As long as you are under [a certain amount of rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges), a third party must review your edit before it becomes visible. But if you see a typo or another error, just go ahead and fix it!

Comment: there is no `complete()` callback on backbone.

Comment: @otmezger No, but there is one in [`jqXHR` objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), which is what `fetch()` returns.